# Webapp that shows a Twitter hashtag live stream?

Tags: web-apps, twitter

We have a computer in the office dedicated to news updates. We would like to add a Twitter stream to it.

Unfortunately, if we try to look at a Twitter hashtag stream (https://twitter.com/hashtag/bitcoin?f=realtime) - instead of it just showing the new results in real time, it shows a button you can click that says "*x* amount of new results".

Are there any applications we can use that show the stream in real time without user interaction?

Comment: Not exactly what you might be looking for, but an idea in case you find no perfect match: there's the Greasemonkey (TamperMonkey, Scriptish) Addon to Firefox (and some other browsers), allowing to "inject" scripts into the currently loaded page. It should be possible to have such a script "push that button" whenever it shows up – which essentially would result in a kind of live-stream. Would that be an acceptable answer to you? Also, maybe you could [edit] your question and include some details on the system (OS/...) requirements?

Answer (score 2):

### [TWUBS](http://twubs.com)

seems to be what you're looking for.

- You can insert a hashtag on the homepage, or go to "http://twubs.com/ [insert hashtag here without "#" symbol]"
- You can change the speed / how fast tweets appear real-time (Fastest, Fast, Medium, Slow, Slower, Slowest)
- You can also "register" a hashtag.

> Users can also “register” a hashtag. Registration does not confer exclusive rights to use of the term in the same sense as registering a copyright or trademark, but it does come with some perks when using the Twubs platform.
>
> For example, users get a brandable hashtag landing page like the one below, which can be used to host Twitter chats. Landing pages can be embedded into websites or used as a standalone page.
>
> [image: branded landing page example]
>
> *- http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/4078-8-Twitter-Hashtag-Tracking-Tools*

- It's [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- It's a [web-apps](/questions/tagged/web-apps) (-s), so it should be [cross-platform](/questions/tagged/cross-platform)

I tried it with various hashtags (like [#dday](http://twubs.com/dday)) myself, and it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch multiple social media sources, then you could take a look at [Flumes](http://flumes.com/), although they're more pitched at marketing professionals, but do have free options.